# How to use ASP.net MVC 3 FileStreamResult to return text generated in .net code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.net webforms, I used to write code to make the browser load a table in Excel by setting the content type to 'application/vnd.ms-excel' and it worked very well.  Now, I'm trying to find the best way to do this in .net.

I've written some .net code that looks like this:

```
public FileStreamResult TaskforceDetailExcelData(string taskforceIdsCommaSeparated)
{
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);
    sw.Write("<html><head></head><body><table>...</table></body></html>");
    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

The result is that I get the following in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

What do I need to do to get my table served to the browser with an excel response type?

Answer (score 0):

try this code. (not tested, but similar to what I do with a text/csv mime type)

```
public FileResult Export()
{
  var csv = "<html><head></head><body><table>...</table></body></html>";
  System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
  byte[] result = encoding.GetBytes(csv);
  return File(result, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "segnalazioni.csv");
}
```